# Passing a variable to a constructor in c++

Tags: c++, class, oop, variables, inheritance

I'm getting started with class inheritance in c++ and I'm really stuck.

From the child class I'm trying to call the parent constructor and pass a variable as a parameter. The warning says *field 'default_name' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]*.

```
class ParentClass {

    public:
        ParentClass(std::string _name): name(_name) {};

        std::string name;

        void printname() {
            std::cout << this->name << std::endl;
        }

}

class DerivedClass: public ParentClass {

    public:

         std::string default_name = "Alex";

         DerivedClass(): ParentClass(default_name) {};

}
```

This obviously does not work because `DerivedClass()` is going to be called before `default_name`is even initialized. Is there a way to construct an object of the parent class from the derived class using a variable?

Comment: `static const std::string default_name = "Alex";` or since C++20 `static constexpr std::string default_name = "Alex";`

Answer (score 2):

Parent classes are constructed ***first***. Even though, in your program, your initialization of `name` appears first, that doesn't mean anything. C++ has strict construction and initialization rules. You are attempting to construct the parent class before `name` gets initialised.

`name` gets constructed ***after*** the parent class gets constructed.

So what you can do is to move `name` into another parent class before the existing one. That one gets constructed first, then your existing constructor will have an initialized member, to work with..

Comment: Thanks! Now, am I supposed to declare a setter function in the parent class and call it from the derived class in order to pass the default_name variable?

Comment: Since you will be calling it in an object that's already constructed, fully, the initialization and construction rules are completely irrelevant and no longer matter.

Comment: See [Base-from-Member](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member).

Answer (score 2):

Members are always initialized in the same order: First base class sub-objects, then members in the order they are listed in the class declaration. Hence, your usage of a default initializer is more or less the same as:

```
class DerivedClass: public ParentClass {
    public:
         std::string default_name;
         DerivedClass(): ParentClass(default_name),default_name("Alex") {};
}
```

Now it is more obvious that `default_name` is passed to the constructor of `ParentClass` before it is initialized. I think you already knew that... to fix it you have several options. As the `default_name` seems to be attached to the `DerivedClass` rather than instances of the class, you can make it static:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class ParentClass {    
    public:
        ParentClass(std::string _name): name(_name) {};    
        std::string name;    
        void printname() {
            std::cout << name;
        }    
};

class DerivedClass: public ParentClass {    
    public:    
         static const std::string default_name;    
         DerivedClass(): ParentClass(default_name) {};    
};

const std::string DerivedClass::default_name = "Alex";

int main(){
    DerivedClass{}.printname();
}
```

Comment: Alternatively using a default value for the constructor also works in this situation, e.g. `DerivedClass(std::string default_name = "Alex")`

Comment: @NotAProgrammer that was my first idea, but I had the feeling that OP wants the default accesible also else where (default parameters aren't) and that `"Alex"` doesnt belong into `ParentClass` (and I didnt realize that one can add another base class inbetween as Sam suggests, which imho is the nicest solution)

Comment: Fair, it's hard to say what approach to use without knowing what OP specifically needs this for.

Answer (score 1):

A base class has to be initialized before the current class members, hence the error. Here, you could make `default_name` static. That way it would be available at object construction time:

```
class DerivedClass: public ParentClass {

    public:

         static std::string default_name;

         DerivedClass(): ParentClass(default_name) {};

};

std::string DerivedClass::default_name = "Alex";
```

Here, `default_name` could (should?) be `const`.But in fact, it would be even simpler to use a literal string here:

```
class DerivedClass: public ParentClass {

    public:

         DerivedClass(): ParentClass("Alex") {};

};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, of course just using a literal string would be easier, but I wanted to understand my mistake.